# How to make font awesome to show on live website

Tags: html, css

I have created a dropdown button and added a font awesome icon, but it is using the unicode and it is not showing up, well it is but as a faint square.

I have search the internet for a solution and the research is stating that make sure the font awesome css style sheet is linked to my html file which it is :/

My HTML is:

```
<div class="language">
    <select>
      <option value="">English</option>
      <option value="">Deutsch</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My Css code is:

```
.language {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -45px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.language select {
  width: 180px;
  border: none;
}
.language::before {
  content: "\f0ac"
}
```

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To use font-awesome icons without appropriate classes, you should also set `font-family`, for example if you are using `Font Awesome 5 Free` you should also set:

```
.language::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f0ac"
}
```

P.S. also make sure you have included `font-awesome` stylesheets

Comment: Nope it is still not showing up

Comment: fixed it, but now it wont move it position and i have tried margin-left ect :/